# VB.NET Format Number with terminating decimal

Tags: vb.net, numbers, format

I have an internal process that requires data in a very specific format. Nothing I can do about that. So in my VB.NET program I am trying to output a number with a terminating decimal and nothing after it. I tried

```
 swOut.WriteLine("{0,10:###0.}", var)
```

But the output is a whole number

```
 886
 913
 941
 971
1002
1034
```

and what I need is

```
 886.
 913.
 941.
 971.
1002.
1034.
```

Must be easy but cant find it in the .NET help.

thanks

~agp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try just moving the decimal point outside of the format specification:

```
swOut.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,10:###0}.", var))
```

You might be able to do it this way too:

```
swOut.WriteLine("{0,10:###0}.", var)
```

Comment: Ahhh got you. I also tried escaping it swOut.WriteLine("{0,10:###0\.}", var)